# How to load react-redux with a simple script tag

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I load the React-Redux (React binding for Redux) JavaScript library onto a web page with a simple script tag?

I have seen examples of loading React-Redux as an NPM module from node_modules, but in my case that is not an option.

I'm after something like this:

```
<!-- load React-Redux with simple script tag -->
<script src="....."></script>

<script>
  // Cannot use npm modules from node_modules, so cannot use
  // import { Provider } from "react-redux";

  // Assign Provider and connect variable if needed from 
  // some symbol defined in the .js file that was loaded 
  // by the script tag
  var Provider = ....;
  var connect = ....;

  // Load my own hypothetical ES6 modules (not relevant to this question)
  import store from "./store";
  import App from "./App";

  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Would love to learn in what case you are in where this is not an option. I have yet to run into that problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is mentioned [right here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact#installing-react-redux).

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@5.0.7/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>`

Then you can basically use `window.ReactRedux`.